# find xpath with specified ID regex

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage with uses the following `<li id="size_name_1" ....>   <li id="size_name_2"....> <li id="size_name_a"` is there a way to find `size_name_NUMBER'` such as

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="size_name_\d+"]')
```

I want to use regex in the id search, Note I use scrapy.

Comment: if you need to find all ids that contains size_name in the id attribute, then try this, "//*[contains(@id,'size_name_')]" . This should return all elements with these id

Comment: @Sureshmani I can but this will also return the elements with letters as well

Comment: You cannot use RegEx'es like this in XPath. You are looking for [`fn:matches()`](https://www.w3.org/XML/Group/qtspecs/specifications/xpath-functions-31/html/Overview.html#func-matches), but I don't know if XPath 2.0 is supported by _scrapy_.

Comment: Are you required to use regex or can you use just xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with css selectors instead by using regex to grab the appropriate ids first. I do note you are using scrapy but same principle should apply.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <li id="size_name_1" > me </li>
  <li id="size_name_2" > and me </li>
  <li id="size_name_a" > but not me :-(</li>
 </body>
</html>
'''

p = re.compile(r'id="(size_name_\d+)"')
ids = p.findall(html)
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for i in ids:
    print(soup.select_one(f'li[id="{i}"]'))
```